# How do I get rid of the block cursor in the GNOME Terminal?

Tags: shortcut-keys, gnome-terminal, cursor

Somehow the GNOME Terminal (Ubuntu 16.04, bash) cursor changed from the standard line cursor to a useless block cursor.

I've encountered this problem before and there was a keyboard shortcut that fixed it, but I can't remember what it was.

Based on what I've gathered from other forum entries I might have entered an input/insert mode. When I press alt + (arrow keys, Up-Down-Right-Left) I get A-B-C-D.

I've tried simply pressing the insert key (laptop keyboard, HP Notebook) to no effect.

To summarise: I have a block cursor. I would like to have the standard line cursor.

Comment: Why is the block cursor useless? Please refrain from making such judgements. In graphical terminal emulators it's by far the most common choice. Furthermore: There isn't and never was a shortcut to change the cursor shape in gnome-terminal. There is a graphical setting (already shown to you in a comment), and an escape sequence. Alt + cursor keys producing letters are unrelated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can change it in Edit -> Profile Preferences -> General Tab.

[image]